# Setting up a double integral over a rectangle

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to compute $\int \int _{R}6x^2y \, dx \, dy$ where $R$ is the rectangle $ [1,2] \times [3,4]$. My difficulty comes from the fact that I don't understand what the rectangle means. I graphed the area such that $1 \le x \le 3$ and $2 \le y \le 4$ and computed the integral $\int_1^3 \int_2^4 6x^2y \,dx \,dy$ but the answer is wrong and bigger.

Comment: The notation $[1,2] \times [3,4]$ refers to the rectangle consisting of points where the $x$ coordinate is in the interval $[1,2]$ and $y$ coordinate in the interval $[3,4]$, so $1 \le x \le 2$ and $3 \le y \le 4$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{x=1}^2 \int_{y=3}^4 6x^2y \,dx \,dy = \int_{x=1}^2 21x^2 dx = 7[2^3 - 1^3] = 49.$$